# Law of Cosine formula that I can't seem to rearrange.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I was in midst of solving a trig problem, and it required using the formula of Law of Cosine. For my case, I had to solve for a specific variable which was $\cos (A)$. Would you show me step-by-step process of how:

$$a^2 = b^2 + c^2 − 2bc\cos (A)$$

turns into

$$\cos(A)= \frac{b^2 + c^2 - a^2}{2bc}$$

Comment: Can you isolate $\cos A$ in your first equation? Try it out.

Comment: $3$ Steps: Add $2bc\cos(A)$to each side, subtract $a^2$ from both sides and lastly divide by $2bc$

Answer (score 3):

$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos(A)$$
Move $2bc\cos(A)$ to the LHS
$$2bc\cos(A)+a^2=b^2+c^2$$
Move $a^2$ to the RHS
$$2bc\cos(A)=b^2+c^2-a^2$$
Divide by $2bc$ on both sides
$$\cos(A)=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$